# How to validate a key in Firebase Rules?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In a Realtime Firebase database, this is my data structure:

```
{'comments': {
  ${project_uuid}: {
     ${thread_uuid}: {
        'author': 12,
        'data': 'who lot of text'
     }
  }
}}
```

I want to validate that inside `comments` there are only uuid Objects. I use [bolt](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/bolt) to generate the Firebase Rules:

```
path /comments {
   read() { auth != null }
   write() { auth != null }

   /{project_uuid} is UuidOnly {
       /{thread_uuid} is Thread;
   }      
}

type Thread {
   author: Number,
   data: String,
}

type UuidOnly {
  validate() {
    // The next line is the problem
    this.parent().key().test(/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}$/)
  }
}
```

In that last line, `key()` doesn't seem to be available as function. How can I do this validation to ensure that inside comments there are only uuid Objects?

Answer (score 0):

greeting nick , try the following

```
type UuidOnly {
  validate() {
    data.test(/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}$/)
  }
}
```

try the above and let me know any

**EDIT (possible fault in pattern match ):**

```
type UuidOnly {
  validate() {
    this.parent().key().test(/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}\-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}$/)
  }
}
```

i am not a pro bolt user but i think here we need to add the escape character before each "-" character in the regular expression used to validate the UUID format. try it.

Comment: This generates `".validate": "data.matches(/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}$/)",`, which returns the error: `No such method/property 'matches'.`

Comment: I also tried `validate() { this.test(/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}$/) }`, which generates `".validate": "newData.val().matches(/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}$/)",`, which for some reason blocks valid objects.

Comment: i am doubting the match pattern so please give the edit part a try and let us know further.

Comment: The suggested code in your edit is the same as what I have in my original post, because bolt compiles `.test` into `.matches`.

Comment: my bad i past the wrong part ,check it now .

Comment: The code you're now suggesting is exactly the same as in the question.

Comment: check the edit part. there is "\" every place before each "-" .  ?